# YouTube Data API v3 is not returning any results when passing the 'publishedBefore','publishedAfter' and the 'nextPageToken' parameters

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Since the youtube in browser does not allow us to select a specific time range(it only has specific filters like 'this year','this month','this week'),I opted to use python API for youtube since I needed to fetch some videos for a specific time range.The youtube API allows for a maximum of 50 results per service call.So,we need to loop over the results and pass the next page token in the subsequent service calls to achieve pagination and extract the data.But,while passing the nextPageToken to the service call,I am not getting any results.The Input and Output of the API calls are mentioned below

```
**1st service call Input:**
part : id,snippet
maxResults : 50
order  : date
publishedAfter : 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z
publishedBefore : 2018-06-07T00:00:00Z
q : rice water hair
type : video

**1st service call Output:**
{
 "nextPageToken: "CDIQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 3957,
 "resultsPerPage": 50
},
 "items":[
    ///it has a list of 20 items even though I have specified max results as 50///
 ]
}

**2nd service call Input:**
part : id,snippet
maxResults : 50
order  : date
pageToken : CDIQAA
publishedAfter : 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z
publishedBefore : 2018-06-07T00:00:00Z
q : rice water hair
type : video

**2nd service call Output:**
{
 "nextPageToken": "CGQQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 3957,
 "resultsPerPage": 50
},
 "items": [
    ///empty list///
 ]
}
```

I have tried the above in google developers console as well as using the python api code.Both are yielding the same output.The total number of results for this query is 3957(found in the output of both api calls).So,I have the **below questions**
1)Why are there no results(empty items list) in the output of the 2nd service call when I pass the nextPageToken in the input?
2)Why is the output of first service call returning only 20 results even though I have specified the max results as 50?

Comment: I am having a similar issue when trying to solve the same problem. The weird thing is that I get this issue now with code that worked when I wrote it about a month ago. I suspect something on their end or does it work for you now?

Comment: Pagination did not work for me.I drastically reduced the time interval(1 hour or 30 minutes) so that I can avoid pagination.I got decent results with this approach